# How to extract values enclosed inside curly braces in PHP?

Tags: php, curly-braces

I have the following values inside curly braces.

{ "address": "test@test.com", "did_you_mean": null, "is_valid": true, "parts": { "display_name": null, "domain": "test.com", "local_part": "test" }}

I need to get the value of "is_valid". I tried json_decode to get the value. But it didn't help me to find the result. Anyone please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Post tried code!!

Comment: You either can do `$object =json_decode($string)`which returns an object, or `$array = json_decode$string, true)` which returns an array. This way, you can do`$object->is_valid` for the first example, or `$array['is_valid']`for the second one

Answer (score 4):

Why json_decode didn't work ?
I tested it with that code and works perfectly:

```
$str= '{ "address": "test@test.com", "did_you_mean": null, "is_valid": true, "parts": { "display_name": null, "domain": "test.com", "local_part": "test" }}';
$obj = json_decode($str);

echo $obj->is_valid;
```